# fedora 21 installation problem

Tags: fedora, partition, windows, system-installation

I have created an unallocated partition of size 45GB in windows, now the partitions are:

1. 200 MB
2. 388 GB C: space
3. 45 GB unallocated
4. lenovo D: drive

Now I tried installing fedora21 and when I log in it shows 45 GB as available space but I don't see the unallocated portion to select it, I see only the other three parts.
Is there a solution without modifying my Windows 7 installation?

Comment: Your partitioning description is very unclear. Please make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Yes, there is a solution.  Your post is not clear - have you successfully installed F21?  If so, please edit your post to include the output of `df -h` and `fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in your post that you have tried creating a new partition in the available space - via Fedora's installer. You may want to try that.